# How to prevent grouping by subject or date when using getThreads() from a label name in Gmail using App-Script?

Tags: multithreading, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

When I am using `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelReceived).getThreads()` it retrieves all the emails that have the same subject and were received on the same date in and outside the given label.
Is there a solution to get the emails from the only given label without grouping it by subject or a date?
Note: that the conversation view is off in the Gmail settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Currently, It seems it is not possible to get the email `messages` labeled with a specific label.  Only the containing `thread`s labeled with a label is retrievable through Apps script built in libraries.

#### Solution:

- Use [Advanced Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) to connect to the [Gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) directly.
- The following snippet gets all messages ids labeled with label name `test`. You may then use [`GmailApp.getMessageById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getmessagebyidid) to transform the message `id` array to `GmailMessage`s

#### Snippet:

```
function getLabelledMessages(labelName = 'test') {
  const labelIds = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me').labels.find(
    labelObj => labelObj.name === labelName
  ).id;
  let messagesList, pageToken;
  do {
    messagesList = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {
      labelIds,
      pageToken,
      maxResults: 100,
    });
    const messages = messagesList.messages;
    if (messages) console.log(JSON.stringify(messages));
  } while ((pageToken = messagesList.nextPageToken) !== undefined);
}
```